# Owner other than window controller in [NSWindowController initWithWindowNibName:owner]?

Tags: cocoa, xib, nswindow, nib, nswindowcontroller

What I would like to know is how does the window controller I initialize with

```
NSWindowController *c=[[NSWindowController alloc] initWithWindowNibName:@"Win" owner:myObj]
```

know which window it should control in the Win.xib file if myObj is not the controller itself? Normally I set the window controller as the owner so that I can set its window in IB with on outlet. Is memory management done all by the window controller even if it is not the owner?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The window controller will do the memory management of the top-level objects even if it's not the owner.  From the `NSWindowController` [class reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSWindowController_Class/Reference/Reference.html):

> Regardless of who is the file’s owner, the window controller is
>   responsible for freeing all top-level objects in the nib file it
>   loads.

The window controller is normally the owner of the NIB, though, and connecting its *window* outlet is usually how it knows which window to control. One could also use the `-setWindow:` method to set it explicitly.

It's conceivable that `NSWindowController` searches the NIB's top-level objects for a window to control if the outlet isn't hooked up, but I don't think it does that.

Have you observed some behavior that you don't understand? What was it?

Comment: If you use a window control to load a NIB and then call `setWindow:`, this has the consequence of all top level NIB objects to be released: From the documentation: `Setting this property releases the window controller’s old window along with any associated top-level objects in its nib file, and establishes ownership of the specified new window.`  So this is certainly never desired.

Answer (score 0):

This method exists for the case that you have a document based app; see `NSDocument`. In that case you'd make an instance of `NSDocument` the owner of the NIB file (`NSDocument` has a `-setWindow:` method but no getter for it). The controller will still get to know its window from the document instance. Code would roughly be:

```
NSDocument * document = ...;
NSWindowController * winCtrl = [[NSWindowController alloc]
   initWithWindowNibName:@"SomeNib" owner:document];
[document addWindowController:winCtrl];
[winCtrl loadWindow];
```

Now the document is owner of the NIB file but the window controller still receives a reference to the window that is assigned to the document.

Of course this code is only for demonstration purposes, the correct way to do it is actually to sub-class `NSDocument`, override `makeWindowControllers`, and initiate all required controllers there.

If your document always only has a single window from a single NIB file, you can also just set the `NSDocument` property `windowNibName` to the name of your NIB file and then call the default `makeWindowControllers` implementation, which roughly does the following:

```
NSWindowController * winCtrl = [[NSWindowController alloc]
   initWithWindowNibName:self.windowNibName owner:self];
[self addWindowController:winCtrl];
```

Also check out the GNUStep implementation of `NSWindowController`, which may be different than the one from Apple (the one from Apple isn't open source, so we cannot know) but it should be equal in behavior:

```
- (void) loadWindow
{
  NSDictionary *table;

  if ([self isWindowLoaded]) 
    {
      return;
    }

  table = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject: _owner forKey: NSNibOwner];
  if ([NSBundle loadNibFile: [self windowNibPath]
        externalNameTable: table
        withZone: [_owner zone]])
    {
      _wcFlags.nib_is_loaded = YES;

      if (_window == nil  &&  _document != nil  &&  _owner == _document)
        {
          [self setWindow: [_document _transferWindowOwnership]];
        }
      else
        {
          // The window was already retained by the NIB loading.
          RELEASE(_window);
        }
    }
  else
    {
      if (_window_nib_name != nil)
        {
      NSLog (@"%@: could not load nib named %@.nib", 
         [self class], _window_nib_name);
    }
    }
}
```

Source:  https://github.com/gnustep/libs-gui/blob/master/Source/NSWindowController.m

It will obtain the window from its document using the private method `_transferWindowOwnership` but only if no window is set after loading, a document is set and this document has been set to be the owner of the loaded NIB file.